# return a different object from view set object python django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have the following Viewset

I have the following models NoteRequest and NoteInfo

```
class NoteRequestViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = NoteInfo.objects.all()

    serializer_class = NoteInfoSerializer

    pagination_class = None
    print(queryset)
    print(serializer_class)

    def list(self, request):
       try:
            obj = self.get_queryset().get(
                Q(refno=pk) | Q(client_id=pk)
            )
            serializer = self.get_serializer(obj)
            return Response(serializer.data)

        except Exception as e:
            return Response(str(e))
```

I want to be able to return a serialized object of NoteInfo rather than NoteRequest but not sure how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: May I know, from where you're getting `pk` ? and which `NoteRequest` are you referring to ?

Comment: @Kingsley Simon As per your view, it will return the serialized form of `NoteInfo` instance.

Comment: @Kingsley Simon Anyway please do add some more info such as `NoteInfoSerializer` class , expected output , current output etc